# Ongoing BIOS and boot issues

Tags: boot, bios

I am having some ongoing issues with booting my computer which came out of nowhere about a month ago. I had not made any modifications to the motherboard, wiring, or any other devices. My motherboard is a P8P67Pro. It's about 7 years old and has been otherwise running reliably up until now.

When I turn on the computer I get a variety of error messages, and it's fairly random as to which set I get.

#### Error set 1

When booting I sometimes get these messages all together:

> New CPU installed! Please enter setup to configure your system.
>
> Chassis intrude! Please check your system.
>
> Fatal Error... System Halted.

I have the same CPU I've had for the last 7 years, and I've touched nothing with respect to that, so the first error message makes no sense. I don't know what the second error message means and can't find any reference to it in the motherboard manual.

If I restart the computer I get no error messages and it all boots as normal.

#### Error set 2

Similar to above. When booting I sometimes get this set of error messages:

> Chassis intrude! Please check your system.
>
> Fatal Error... System Halted.

As above, just a simple reset will resolve it, and the computer will boot as normal.

#### Error set 3

The final set of error messages is a bit different. Sometimes it just comes up with this:

> Please enter setup to recover BIOS settings.

I then press F1 to go to the BIOS settings, then change nothing there (i.e. stick with the defaults for everything), then save and exit BIOS. The computer will then boot as normal.

#### Summary

Almost every time I turn on my computer I get one of the above sets of error messages and it fails to boot. I can temporarily resolve the issue and get it to boot properly, but the next time I turn on my computer I will experience the same issue. Does anyone have any idea what might be happening here, or can suggest some diagnostic tests to try?

Comment: Replace the battery. All those errors are because the BIOS settings aren't being kept.

Comment: Might be the motherboard's battery is dying, losing some settings. Try replacing the battery.

Comment: I've just changed the battery and set up the BIOS, and it appears to be working now. My computer boots up without any errors. Thanks GabrielaGarcia and Xen2050. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to be due to the motherboard battery dying, and therefore the BIOS settings not being retained. Thanks @GabrielaGarcia and @Xen2050 for the suggestion. This is just a more detailed explanation for anyone who wants to replicate what I did.

The following instructions will replace the motherboard battery, then recover the BIOS settings that would have been lost due to the battery being removed. Once complete the computer should consistently boot without any issues.

1. Turn off the computer. Disconnect power cord.
2. Open up case.
3. Locate battery on motherboard. It will likely be the size and shape of a small coin. Consult your motherboard manual if you have any issues finding it.
4. (optional) If battery is inaccessible, remove any cables or other items blocking access, and make note of what went where.
5. Take note of battery orientation. It will probably have the side with text on it facing out.
6. Remove battery. See your motherboard manual for more details if it's not obvious how to do this.
7. Replace with new battery. Most computers need a CR2032 battery, but just make sure it's the same type that you just removed from the motherboard. It will say on one side of the battery.
8. Reconnect any cables/etc that you disconnected in step 4.
9. Reconnect power cord. Turn computer on.
10. During startup you will likely get a message saying "Please enter setup to recover BIOS settings." Follow on-screen instructions to enter BIOS.
11. Choose whatever settings you usually prefer, including setting up the date and time, then select 'save and exit'. Or simply choose 'save and exit' without modifying anything to just go with the default settings.
12. If you did not adjust the clock in BIOS, then once computer has booted, log into an admin account.
13. Click on the computer clock in the bottom right corner. Select 'change date and time settings'
14. Set to current date and time, then click 'ok'.

Comment: Update: it's now been nearly a week since I changed the battery and the issues have not returned. Prior to this they occurred daily. It's safe to say this issue is solved.